# how can we create a hyperlink icon on watson conversation?

Tags: watson-conversation, watson

We'd like create a hyperlink icon on watson conversation, when user click that icon, it redirects to watson explorer or discovery or any internet url, any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conversation returns text. It is up to your applications UI to render what is sent back.

So you can use HTML or any kind of meta tags.

Answer (score 0):

HTML can be added and sent back in the response.text field, have a look at how its done in the image below, its pretty straight forward:

- [Image Link: Embed HTML in Watson Conversation response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSlKL.png)
- Also, you may like to go through this guide on Watson Conversation: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/assistant/tutorial.html#tutorial

Hope this helps.